# How can I dynamically allocate memories for 4-D array with 2-D fixed array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I dynamically allocate memories for 4-D array with 2-D fixed array in c++

I know the way of assigning 3-D array with 2-D fixed array in this way

```
int n = 100;
double (*a)[4][5];
a = new double[n][4][5];
```

but in the 4-D case, what should I do?

```
int n = 100;
int m = 1000;
double (*(*a))[4][5];
a = new double[m][][4][5] ???
```

It is possible to avoid this problem by using quadruple pointer
(double**** a), but I need fixed matrix ([4][5]) in my code system.
please help

Comment: Because primitive type doesn't really nead their (do-nothing) constructor be called, I think you can use `malloc` instead of `new` => `double *a = malloc(m * n * 4 * 5 * sizeof(double));`

Comment: After seen the answer that suggest to use vector, I think my previous proposition is totally out

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using pointers and keeping track of memory you should use a vector.

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>> vector4d(dim1, vector<vector<vector<int>>>(dim2, vector<vector<int>>(4, vector<int>(5, 0))))
```